# Why MVP still considered tightly coupled even contract(interfaces) are used

Tags: android, mvp, solid-principles, android-mvp, tightly-coupled-code

With loosely coupled what I understand that interaction between classes/objects has to be through interfaces or abstract classes moreover according to my understanding any dependency should come from outside class(dependency injection) instead of instantiating inside class. **(correct me if my understanding of loosely coupling system is wrong)**

Now when I read advantages and disadvantages of MVP architecture in Android, tightly coupling of view and presenter is common disadvantage even though contract and dependency injection is used, can anybody justify this?

Thanks in advance